# Is it possible to gain the precise position of a live mysql database when performing full backup

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, mysqlbinlog

I have a production database that I usually run fullbackups on once every week. I have bin logs turned on for incremental backups.

The production server is on the west coast while business hours are on the east coast.

When I perform the fullback up I query the master for is log and position. I put these values in the filename of the zip that I compress the databases to.

I'm having difficulties using mysqlbinlog to create incremental sql file from a certain position that I know the backup has ended at.

Would running `Show Master Status` then then running `mysqldump --flush-logs --single-transaction...` suffice to get accurate information in order to restore.

I know the ideal setup is to backup a slave database since locking won't hurt the production environment but at the moment I haven't made the switch.

Am I not getting the desirable results because I'm not locking all the tables?

Thanks in advance

EDIT

I realized with the help of RolandoMySQLDBA that I wasn't pointing to the appropriate binlog file. I was instead pointing to the whole directory `binlog/bin-log.[0-9]* > sql.txt`. So with just the position I was hitting logs that started much earlier than desired. So I changed my script to pull the appropriate binlog file as well as the position and that worked like a charm.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you are using mysqldump, you can get the binary logs coordinates of the backup at the point-in-time of the the mysqldump's start.

Just add the [--master-data option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_master-data)

```
mysqldump --master-data=2 --flush-logs --single-transaction...
```

Using `--master-data=2` will record the binary log filename and position in the form of a  `CHANGE MASTER TO` command. It is recorded as a comment.

Using `--master-data=1` will also record the binary log filename and position in the form of a  `CHANGE MASTER TO` command. It is not recorded as a comment, but as a command that will be executed when you reload the mysqldump.

In both cases, you can always find that `CHANGE MASTER TO` command on line 23 of the dump. I mentioned this before in my old post [MySQL Exec_Master_Log_Pos value greater than Read_Master_Log_Pos](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22623/mysql-exec-master-log-pos-value-greater-than-read-master-log-pos/22636#22636) under the **heading "BUT WAIT..."**

To retrieve that line from a mysqldump file named `myfullbackup.sql`, simply run

```
head -23 myfullbackup.sql | tail -1 > MasterLogFilePos.sql
```

and the `CHANGE MASTER TO` command will be in it

If you run the mysqldump with

```
mysqldump --master-data=2 --flush-logs --single-transaction...
```

the Master will continue allowing reads and writes to all InnoDB tables.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!