# How do I fix Replication event checksum verification failed while reading from network. Error_code: 1743

Tags: mysql, replication

Our server had disk space problems. As a result, replication's IO Threads fails to start.

Here are the errors in mysql error log:

> [Note] Slave I/O thread: connected to master
>   'user@host:3307',replication started in log 'mysql-bin.000030' at
>   position 196820914
>
> [ERROR] Slave I/O: Replication event checksum verification failed
>   while reading from network. Error_code: 1743
>
> [ERROR] Slave I/O: Relay log write failure: could not queue event from
>   master, Error_code: 1595

How do I fix the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try resetting the relay logs as follows:

```
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO master_log_file='mysql-bin.000030',master_log_pos=196820914;
START SLAVE;
```

This will erase all relay logs in the Slave, starting with a fresh one. It should start retrieving binlog events from the Master. If it fails again, then `mysql-bin.000030` on the Master may be corrupt. In that event, you would have to set up replication from scratch by doing this:

- Stop the DB Application
- On the Master, `RESET MASTER;`
- mysqldump the data from the Master
- Load the mysqldump on the Slave
- On the Slave, run `STOP SLAVE;`
- On the Slave, run `CHANGE MASTER TO master_log_file='mysql-bin.000001',master_log_pos=4;`
- On the Slave, run `START SLAVE;`

## CAVEAT

Make sure the network connection is clear (with no dropped packets) between Master and Slave.

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked perfectly!
I had mysql-bin corrupted on the Master.

Comment: `CHANGE MASTER TO master_log_file='mysql-bin.000001',master_log_pos=4;` is of course not generally correct - you need to adjust the log file name and log position for your needs.

Comment: @David you can use position 4 in all versions of MySQL back to at least 4.1 when doing non-GTID replication. See my November 2014 post where I discuss that (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82998/question-on-having-a-mysql-5-1-replicate-from-a-mysql-5-6-db/83010#83010). Also, see how the MySQL 5.7 Documentation still uses it (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/change-master-to.html). I have used it two days ago in a 5.7 setup without incident. Using positions from specific versions as works  (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12530/mysql-master-binlog-corruption/12531#12531)

Comment: STOP SLAVE: and START SLAVE: were enough to get it working again for me. Probably won't work in most cases but its worth a shot.